# How to reference remote projects in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, xcode-project

I've dragged and dropped a remove `.xcodeproj` that's being updated via GitHub. It shows up in the file tree, but I can't reference the code. Do I need to add an import statement or do something extra? There's so much outdated and conflicting info out there and couldn't get it to work with Xcode 6 and Swift. Thanks for any help or direction.

Comment: You will have top copy the whole project source (which makes sense via git anyway) not only the `xcodeproj`. N.B. I guess you mean remote, not remove ;-)